# Quotient with squareroots

Tags: calculus, geometry

Why is $\dfrac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1+t}} = \sqrt{1-t}?$

And conversely $\dfrac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t}}= \sqrt{1+t}$?

I used it in an assignment because maple said it's true but I want to know why and can't seem to figure it out. Is it because there are som rules with adding squareroots like there are rules with multiplying them? Ie. $ \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ due to rules for powers?

Comment: You are correct. For positive $a$ and $b$ the identity $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$ holds. Thus $$\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1+t}} = \sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t}} = \sqrt{1-t}.$$

Comment: You might as well write the factorization with the conjugate rule: $\sqrt{\frac{(1-t)(1+t)}{1+t}}$, for clarity.

Comment: Thanks guys. Makes perfect sense when using the factorization!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{1-t^2}= \sqrt{(1-t)(1+t)} =\sqrt{1-t}\cdot\sqrt{1+t}$$

Cancel common factors in each. You can also rewrite as follows:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1+t}} = \sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t}} = = \sqrt{\frac{(1-t)(1+t)}{1+t}}=\sqrt{1-t}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)$. Just pay attention to the sign of the expression, and you can manipulate the square roots.

Answer (score 0):

$$\underbrace{(1-t)}_a\underbrace{(1+t)}_{b}=1-t+t-t^2=\underbrace{1-t^2}_{ab}$$
Also:
$$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$1-t^2=-(t^2-1)=-(t-1)(t+1)$$

From here you can deduce pretty much everything using the a, b product thing you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1+t}} = \frac{\sqrt{(1+t)(1-t)}}{\sqrt{1+t}} = \frac{\color{red}{{\sqrt{1+t}}}\sqrt{1-t}}{\color{red}{\sqrt{1+t}}} = \sqrt{1-t}.$$